# Is there any function to split data in R, depending on a certain value?

Tags: r, select, subset

I want to create a new table with these conditions:  all the data that in transition=13-14 was size_age=j.

[image]

Comment: Hi nala, it would be easier to help if you provide your data using `dput()` instead of a screenshot. Also, what do you mean by split? What outcome are you specifically looking for?

Comment: I would like to select all the individuals that the first year were size_age "j", but also the next years, not only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr::filter, with conditions to get your desired subset

```
dplyr::filter(df, transition =="13-14", size_age=="j")
```